# EF using context.Database.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF6 in my project. All fine until I want to step outside the general domain-entityframework world.

I want to use a custom bit of sql to return the columns from a given table. The SQL works fine in SSMS and if I just want to return a single string column this works fine as in (1).

The problems start when I try to return a number of columns and map them to an entity class as in (2).

First off it complains about foreign key relationships (lazy loading?) so I fake them by calling a repository that builds them. That sorts that. (I have a dataset entity that has 3 child entities)

Now I get the error "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'Dataset'. Previously found CLR type 'Meta.EF.Dataset', newly found CLR type 'Meta.Entities.Dataset'."

Why in (2) is it caring about the rest of the context and its relationships? I just want to execute a piece of SQL against the database? I haven't asked it to do anything like this. Can I tell it not to?

Or just step outside EF for this sort of thing?

Thanks

```
public List<SchemaItem> GetColumnsForTable(string tableName)
    {
        var returnStrings = new List<string>();
        var returnObjects = new List<SchemaItem>();

        //(1) THIS WORKS FINE
        var query2 =
           "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TestMetaAdmin.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" +
           tableName + "'";

        using (var context = new TestMetaAdminEntities())
        {
            returnStrings = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query2).ToList();
        }
        //END (1)

        //(2) THIS DOESN'T
        var query =
            "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM TestMetaAdmin.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" +
            tableName + "'";

        using (var context = new TestMetaAdminEntities())
        {
            var datasetRepo = new DatasetRepo();
            var dummy = datasetRepo.GetAll();

            returnObjects = context.Database.SqlQuery<SchemaItem>(query).ToList();
        }
        //END (2)

        return returnObjects;
    }


public class SchemaItem
{

    public string COLUMN_NAME { get; set; }
    public bool IS_NULLABLE { get; set; }
    public string DATA_TYPE { get; set; }
    public int CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `SchemaItem` in the EDMX file instead ? I don't have it available right now, but if you right click in it, can't you add a new entity ? Kind of "code first" entity, which I've never used personally.

Comment: I have to then map that to something in the database... and it is a system view rather than a user table so its getting more complicated... I've stepped out of EF and written something in 15 mins but I'd like to understand this a bit more (especially if you map it to a string it doesn't seem to worry about the rest of the context!?)

Comment: Check which line it's failing on. It looks like your `var datasetRepo = new DatasetRepo();` and `var dummy = datasetRepo.GetAll();` don't get used so could be removed. As the error message mentions an ambiguous entity called `Dataset` I'm wondering whether it's actually failing on one of these lines.

Comment: hi, these lines work fine. they are just there because it complains about the fk relationships in the context if not (these lines return an object that has the three foreign keys that it complains about not being there)... this is what i don't understand - all the errors relate to the objects and relationships within the context. I am trying to map it to a separate entity - does this need to be within the context?

Comment: @GraemeMiller I would think you can great an entity in the EDMX file and need not to commit the DDL to the database.

Comment: The definition is "The type of object returned by the query"... not very clear - is this saying the object must map to an entity framework object?

Comment: I tried that but it complained about there being no table mapping

Comment: @FrancisDucharme - "Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - SchemaItems" .... I could "Generate Database From Model" but I don't want to do this... thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the EF backdoor, use stright-up ADO.NET, SQL Command objects and a datareader?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database.aspx

Your connection to the database would be what you see being done when using Entity-SQL

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738684%28v=vs.100%29.aspx